# Word breaking for two sentences

Tags: page-breaking

I have written following command:

```
\newcommand{\ger}[2]{{\noindent\raisebox{-0.2mm} 
{\includegraphics[width=5.47mm,height=3.28mm]{Flag_1.pdf}} 
\color{red} #1\nopagebreak\\\raisebox{-0.2mm}{\includegraphics{pol.pdf}}  
\color{blue} \emph{#2}}\vspace{5pt}}
```

This is going to be used as follows:

```
\ger{First sentence}{Second sentence}
```

Question is, how to assert that these two sentences will be always on the same page with full content (there won't be any page breaks)? I tried to use \nopagebreak, but it still breaks sometimes part of the second sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `\\` you can use `\par\nobreak` to prevent page breaks:

```
\newcommand{\ger}[2]{{\noindent\raisebox{-0.2mm} 
{\includegraphics[width=5.47mm,height=3.28mm]{Flag_1.pdf}} 
\color{red} #1\par\nobreak\noindent\raisebox{-0.2mm}{\includegraphics{pol.pdf}}  
\color{blue}\emph{#2}}\vspace{5pt}}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to put the whole thing in a \minipage, and make that mini page a float.

**Edit**

Per request, an example:

```
\newcommand{\ger}[2]{%
  \begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \noindent
      \raisebox{-0.2mm}{\includegraphics[width=5.47mm,height=3.28mm]{Flag_1.pdf}} 
      \color{red}{#1}\\
      \raisebox{-0.2mm}{\includegraphics{pol.pdf}}  
      \color{blue}{\emph{#2}}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}}
```

You may want to add a `\caption` and a `\label` as well.

Comment: I think this is the simpler, cleaner solution as a concept, but I'm not going to vote it up, unless you'd like to provide sufficiently simple example code...

Comment: @Brent: Example code added.

Comment: why a float?

Comment: @egreg: A float isn't essential here. However, my experience is that tall boxes/minipages often create overfull/underfull vbox  problems. At least in my usage, those tall boxes/minipages almost always result from describing something graphically or tabularly: A figure or a table.